# Scale ImageView to fit ToolBar with overlap

Tags: android, layout, imageview, android-toolbar

I want to center an ImageView on to top of my ToolBar and make it overlap.

Here is what it should look like:

[image: Goal]

The black rectangle is supposed to be the Toolbar and the gray rectangle with the semi-cicrle is the ImageView that I want to place on top of the toolbar so that the **semi circle overlaps** the toolbar.

My Toolbar looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/actionbar_bg"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now if I place the ImaveView on top it is too big:

[image: Problem]

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/addbtn_bg"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
/>
```

But if I set it `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/toolbar"` then it fits perfectly but the semi circle isn't overlapping:

[image: ProblemII]

Is there a way I can achieve this?
Maybe by using something like guidelines to make only the rectangle part of the ImageView to align?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would have to have a separate semicircle, that uses the `below="@id/toolbar"`

Comment: If I do that, the semi-circle is too big.
Basically whats happening is that the mid section image (The rectangle part of it) is being scaled down but the ImageView Border stays the same. 
So the semi circle is being adjusted according to the border and not the actual image.
Even if i use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` It doesnt work.

Comment: what about adding a margin to the bottom of the toolbar?

Comment: Well the problem isn't the bottom part but the width of the semi circle. The width is being adjusted according to the ImageView of the mid-part. Sorry i forgot to say that.

Comment: is the semicircle and the square 1 image that is being used as the background?

Comment: The Semi-circle and the square are two separate ImageViews. Both don't have the background attribute but the src attribute.

Comment: sorry, but the only thing i can suggest is you separate the two.
have the square to use android:layout_alignBottom="@id/toolbar"

And the semicircle to use layout_Below="@id/toolbar"

Answer (score 0):

Okay we solved it.
Using the tip from [matty357](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4687050/matty357), I changed the ImageView in two separate ImageViews (A Rectangle and semi-circle) and instead of assigning the rectangle ImageView a src attribute, I made it take a background attribute using this file:

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <nine-patch
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/title_bar_9"
            android:dither="true"
            />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

It's using a 9-Patch Image to be able to scale it down aswell.
Works like a charm now! Thanks!